# \encl{} with multiple lines in lettre class

Tags: errors, lists, itemize, french, lettre

I use `lettre` class for French letters and, in the `\encl{}` I need to specify multiples lines.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Service des réclamations}
    \name{Jean Râleur}
    \address{Jean Râleur. 4, rue du Bac à sable. 80886 Sassone-le-Creux}
    \lieu{Sassone-le-Creux}
    \telephone{01 02 03 04 05}
    \email{jean.raleur@fai.fr}
    \nofax

    \def\concname{Objet :~} % On définit ici la commande 'objet'
    \conc{rétractation}
    \opening{Madame, Monsieur,}

    Vous m'avez démarché la semaine dernière
    pour me proposer l'édition de luxe de l'encyclopédie Wikipédia,
    pour la somme de 5000.
    Conformément à la loi m'accordant un délai de rétractation de 7~jours,
    je renonce à mon achat et demande le remboursement de la somme versée.


    \closing{Je vous prie d'agréer,
        Madame, Monsieur,
    mes salutations distinguées.}

    \encl{\begin{itemize}
        \item Document 1
        \item Document 2
    \end{itemize}}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I compile it with `xelatex main.tex`, so it work fine until I get the wollowing message:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36     ^^I\end{itemize}}

?
```

So, I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and everything work fine as you can see:

[image: main.pdf.png]

The problem come from the `\encl{}` command. If I just put on line on it, I didn’t get this error message.

So how can I use multiple lines in the `\encl{}` command without having this error message?

Comment: You should add a newline before your code blocks, so that `\documentclass...` and `! LaTeX Error...` is in the code block.

Comment: Comment aside: If you compile with `xelatex`, don't load `inputen` not`fontenc`. As to `lmodern`, it's the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `enumitem` and use a minipage:

```
\encl{ \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}\begin{itemize}[wide = 0pt]
 \item Document 1
 \item Document 2
 \end{itemize}\end{minipage}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd define a `\multiencl` command that makes a tabular:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{lettre}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\multiencl}[1]{%
  \encl{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\labelitemi\ }l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Service des réclamations}

\name{Jean Râleur}
\address{Jean Râleur. 4, rue du Bac à sable. 80886 Sassone-le-Creux}
\lieu{Sassone-le-Creux}
\telephone{01 02 03 04 05}
\email{jean.raleur@fai.fr}
\nofax

\renewcommand\concname{Objet :~} % On définit ici la commande 'objet'
\conc{rétractation}

\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}

Vous m'avez démarché la semaine dernière
pour me proposer l'édition de luxe de l'encyclopédie Wikipédia,
pour la somme de 5000.
Conformément à la loi m'accordant un délai de rétractation de 7~jours,
je renonce à mon achat et demande le remboursement de la somme versée.


\closing{Je vous prie d'agréer,
   Madame, Monsieur,
   mes salutations distinguées.}

\multiencl{
  Document 1 \\
  Document 2
}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]